# How to deal with micro- or nanoseconds in datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime

I imported `.xls` files which appear now as

```
0      2022-09-27 11:56:22.733740
1      2022-09-27 11:56:22.733940
2      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734140
3      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734340
4      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734540
           
4995   2022-09-27 11:56:23.732740
4996   2022-09-27 11:56:23.732940
4997   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733140
4998   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733340
4999   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733540
Name: time, Length: 5000, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Apparently, the numbers from `.` on are in ns(?). Is there a way to convert these numbers into a more readable format?

Comment: Define "more readable".  The NumPy(?) datatype can *accomodate* billionths of a second, but in this case you don't seem to have more than microsecond resolution from whatever generated the data. (E.g. 733740 microseconds == 733740000 nanoseconds)

Comment: Technically, the `.` is a just a decimal point, so in the first line, `22.733740` is the number of seconds.

Comment: This is perfectly readable to me. You need to be more clear about what format you want. How would you define "more readable".

Comment: I assume the excel data is imported to a pandas dataframe; the default string representation of a datetime series is what you see; see also [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (pandas uses a space character as date/time separator).

Comment: Thanks for your input! When these numbers are milliseconds then I guess I cannot convert them into another format or least not one that is more convenient? I do not read seconds plus their milliseconds so often :) Is it e.g. possible to separate the ms and µs like " 732 : 740 " or the like?
However, when these are milliseconds, why is pandas telling it would datetime64[ns]?

Comment: `datetime64[ns]` is the data type, the "ns" means it can store up to nanosecond precision, but it doesn't have to. Please note that the data type has no "format", what you see is just the string representation of what is stored in the underlying data structure. You could create separate columns for milli- and microseconds, but why? what do you want to do with the data that requires this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have microseconds but you can `floor` the datetime columns for more readability (but you lost information):

```
>>> df['time'].dt.floor('s')  # seconds

0      2022-09-27 11:56:22
1      2022-09-27 11:56:22
2      2022-09-27 11:56:22
3      2022-09-27 11:56:22
4      2022-09-27 11:56:22
4995   2022-09-27 11:56:23
4996   2022-09-27 11:56:23
4997   2022-09-27 11:56:23
4998   2022-09-27 11:56:23
4999   2022-09-27 11:56:23
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# Or
>>> df['time'].dt.floor('ms')  # milliseconds
0      2022-09-27 11:56:22.733
1      2022-09-27 11:56:22.733
2      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734
3      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734
4      2022-09-27 11:56:22.734
4995   2022-09-27 11:56:23.732
4996   2022-09-27 11:56:23.732
4997   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733
4998   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733
4999   2022-09-27 11:56:23.733
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: you can also use `round` and `ceil`.

Comment: Why would you *modify* the data, just to make it more "readable" (which is subjective anyway)? Maybe `strftime` would be a better alternative if you want to create "human-friendly" (might exclude programmers) representations of date and time...